# Spring mongoTemplate Aggregation not wokrs well... help me plz

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

i'm using mongoTemplate at spring boot, and i wannt to write query using mongoTemplate Aggregation, but i can't.. query i wanna use is this

```
$project: {
        root:"$root",
      name: "$root.name",
      like: "$root.like",
      songs: {
        _id: "$root.songs._id",
        name: "$root.songs.name",
        lyrics: "$root.songs.lyrics",
        like: "$root.songs.like",
        view: "$root.songs.view",
        video: "$video"
      }
    }
```

and i trying to use this query with spring mongo db...  like

```
Aggregation.project()
      .andExpression("root").as("root")
      .andExpression("root.name").as("name")
      .andExpression("root.like").as("like")
      .andExpression("root.songs._id").as("songs._id")
      .andExpression("root.songs.name").as("songs.name")
      .andExpression("root.songs.lyrics").as("songs.lyrics")
      .andExpression("root.songs.like").as("songs.like")
      .andExpression("root.songs.view").as("songs.view")
      .andExpression("root.songs.video").as("songs.video"));
```

but i think it is wrong, what i want to do is this

```
  songs: {
            _id: "$root.songs._id",
            name: "$root.songs.name",
            lyrics: "$root.songs.lyrics",
            like: "$root.songs.like",
            view: "$root.songs.view",
            video: "$video"
          }
```

but real query is made by that 'Java Code'  is this

```
{
  "$project": {
    "root": "$root",
    "name": "$root.name",
    "like": "$root.like",
    "songs._id": "$root.songs._id",
    "songs.name": "$root.songs.name",
    "songs.lyrics": "$root.songs.lyrics",
    "songs.like": "$root.songs.like",
    "songs.view": "$root.songs.view",
    "songs.video": "$root.songs.video"
  }
```

how can i make query using mongoTemplate project() method??

Comment: Please post what the input document looks like _and_ the document structure to look like _after_ the `$project` stage.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to use querydsl in conjction with mongoTemplate.One of the more common ways to query MongoDB with Spring Data is by making use of the Query and Criteria classes – which very closely mirror native operators.

You create the query and insert the condition in the query you created like below:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is("your-name"));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("like").is("your-like"));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("songs._id").is("your-song-id"));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("songs.name").is("your-song-name"));
//and so on you continue with the rest
```

And after finishing building the query you execute it like below:

```
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query,Project.class);
```

Also very important you should have domain classes of Project and Song created. I am assumming you have created this classes.

```
class Project {
 //attributes
 List<Song> songs;
}
```

```
class Song {
 //attributes
}
```

For more information regarding querydsl with MongoDB you can refer the links below:
https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb
http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s07.html